# Circles inside a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I need to create a figure like this:

[image]

And my poor code is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rounded corners=15pt]
(10,0) rectangle ++(15,3);
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (5,1) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this code does not work since the circle will be outside the rectangle, which I don't want.

So my question is:

Why does this code not work? In other programmes when you put a loop inside a loop it works as expected, but here putting a `tikzpicture` inside a `tikzpicture` does not work as I'd expect. That is, how do nested `tikzpicture`s work in TikZ in general?

Comment: In general, nesting `tikzpicture`s do not work. In some cases, you may get away with it. But you should generally expect it to break.

Comment: I've tried to edit your question. Could you make sure that I've understood you correctly? I've also retagged it because `tikz-pic` is not appropriate here, and replaced the misleading use of `pic` in your question. In TikZ, `pic`s are a specific construct. You aren't using them, so they are irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate for making the question better and clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to nest ***loops***. However, nesting `tikzpicture` environments is known to be hazardous. Although it sometimes works, it should be avoided. Basically, it is expected to break.

What I would do is to draw the circles *first* and the `fit` the outer box around them. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
  \coordinate (c0) at (0,0);
  \foreach \i [count=\j, evaluate=\j as \k using \j-1, evaluate=\j as \m using { int(mod(\j,5))==0 ? "" : "draw" }, evaluate=\j as \n using { \j>10 ? "20mm" : "10mm" }] in {1,...,11}
  \node (c\j) [right=7.5pt of c\k |- c0, circle, anchor=north west, minimum size=\n, \m] {};
  \node [fit=(c1) (c11), draw, rounded corners=15pt, inner xsep=5mm, minimum height=30mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: radio]

If you prefer, you can simply draw the circles one-by-one and then draw the box in the same way. Just name the leftmost and rightmost so that you can say `fit=(<name 1>) (<name 2>)` and all should be well.

In this particular case, you could, if you really wanted, nest the `tikzpicture`s. However, `(5,1)` is at `x=5cm`, well to the left of the leftmost border of the box which is at `x=10cm`. So to put it in the box, you'd need to put it in the box.

You also need to put the `tikzpicture` inside a node. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [rounded corners=15pt] (10,0) rectangle ++(15,3);
  \node at (12.5,1.5) {% BREAKAGE EXPECTED !!
    \begin{tikzpicture}% DON"T TRY THIS AT HOME !!
      \draw circle (1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: circle in box]

But there is not much point in courting disaster when it would be much easier to write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [rounded corners=15pt] (10,0) rectangle ++(15,3);
  \draw (12.5,1.5) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the same result without the attendant risks and much more easily.

Comment: Nice overview/explanation, however I got one more brain fold when figured out first solution (+1)   :-)

Comment: @Zarko Are you suggesting it is my solution which requires too much thinking? :-)

Comment: no, I try to make a joke, that both solutions are similar complicated :-), however you offer more options, answer is more complete and consequently  you lead :-) :-). With high respect,

Answer (score 5):

One of many possible solution (considering the first @cfr comment):

```
\documentclass[border=11mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style = {draw, rounded corners=15pt,
              minimum width=150mm, minimum height=30mm}
                    ]
\node (a)   [box] {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \draw ($(a.west)+(1.1*\i,0.5)$) circle (5mm);
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \draw ($(a.west)+(5+1.1*\i,0.5)$) circle (5mm);
\draw ($(a.east)-(2,0)$) circle (10mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution requires too much thinking! (+1)